# Joining React props with custom props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When defining props in React, using Typescript, it seems that the default React props get overwritten by whatever the interface is. Is there a clean way to merge the two without having to specify every prop React already knows about?

Example:

```
interface IProps { // extends React.???
   title: string;
   // Generally seen adding children?: any
   // But this can get out of hand with onClick, onChange, etc
}

function MyComponent(props: IProps) {
   return props.children; // Typescript error: children doesn't exist on props
}
```

Comment: Just that having to readd every property that React already knows about gets to be tedious.

Comment: Typescript doesn't get that the component has access the to basic React props when defining additional/custom props. They seem to be overwritten. So Typescript will throw an error saying, for example, children isn't a property of props.

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to as "React default props" aka "every prop React already knows about" are more properly called "props accepted by any React DOM element wrapper component", i.e. `onClick`, `className`, etc.

**Default props** typically refers to the static `defaultProps` property on a `React.Component`, with which you provide default values for any props that were not passed to your component.

**`onClick`, `className`, etc. are not reserved prop names** and you can use them however you want in your own components, for instance you could have your component expect `className` to be a function (regardless of whether it's a good idea).  The only reserved prop names that work on React elements of any kind (at the time of writing) are `key` and `ref`, and they're not really true props because they're not available to your component's render method.

**Passing `onClick` to your own component does not automatically register a click handler**.  It will only do so if you pass the `onClick` you received to a `<div>`, `<button>`, or other React DOM Element wrapper that you render somewhere down the line.  **If you don't do anything with a prop you were passed, it has no effect** (besides possibly causing a pure render component to update when it otherwise wouldn't).

For example, the following component will not respond to clicks:

```
const ClickFail = props => <button />
render(<ClickFail onClick={...} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

But the following will:

```
const ClickSuccess = props => <button onClick={props.onClick} />
render(<ClickSuccess onClick={...} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

And you could pass `onClick` to only one subelement if you really wanted:

```
const ClickButtonOnly = props => (
  <form>
    <input placeholder="ignores clicks" />
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>Handles Clicks</button>
  </form>
)
```

Or you could pass in multiple click handlers with different names:

```
const SimpleForm = props => (
  <form>
    <button onClick={props.onCancelClick}>Cancel</button>
    <button onClick={props.onOKClick}>OK</button>
  </form>
)
```

**Also keep in mind that some DOM element wrappers accept props that others do not**, for instance `readOnly` applies only to `<input>` and `<textarea>`.

**You can even require `children` to be whatever type you want.** For instance, you can pass a function as the `children` of a component and use it (again, not the best use of React, but just to illustrate what's possible):

```
type Props = {
  value: number,
  children: (value: number) => number,
}
const ApplyFunction = (props: Props) => (
  <div>{React.Children.only(props.children)(props.value)}</div>
)

render(
  <ApplyFunction value={3}>
    {value => value * value}
  </ApplyFunction>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
// renders <div>9</div>
```

So you see, `IProps` does not necessarily have to extend anything.

However, it is common to pass along rest props to a React DOM Element wrapper (e.g. `<div {...props}>...</div>` and as you were asking, it would be nice to be able to check the type of all of those input properties to your component.

I think you could do the following with Flow to check the types correctly, but unfortunately I don't think there's any Typescript equivalent (someone correct me if I'm wrong):

```
type Props = React.ElementProps<typeof 'div'> & {
  title: string,
}
const MyComponent = (props: Props) => (
  <div {...props}>
    {props.title}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this extensive explanation! I was looking for this information, thank you for this exhaustive answer. @dpaulus, if you come back here, you should consider marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should define that your stateless functional component will return `React.SFC<YourProps>`.

Try this

```
import * as React from "react";
const MyComponent: React.SFC<IProps> = (props) => {
  return props.children;
}
```

If you want to use class-based component, you can extend your class with `React.Component<YourProps(optional), YourState(optional)>` instead

For example

```
import * as React from "react"
class MyComponent extends React.Component<IProps> {
  public render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div>...</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't really get at the author's confusion about how props like `onClick`, `className`, etc. are handled in React.

Answer (score 0):

```js
type TitleProps = { // your custom props
  level?: level;
  color?: string;
};

const Title = (props: TitleProps & React.Component['props']) => { // join default props and custom props
    const { level = 'h1', color, children } = props; // joined props containing default props
    return <Text style={[styles[level], color && { color }]}>{children}</Text>;
}
```

I was able to solve the problem by this way.